# Alternative ways to display Scalatest results

Tags: scala, scalatest

I am thinking about setting up an automated acceptance testing suite with Scalatest and output the results into a simple web dashboard (say print each scenario text stacked with check marks or crosses next to them). Is there a built-in functionality I can use for alternative ways to display the ordinary output or would I need to output and parse the logs myself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider creating a custom [`Reporter`](http://doc.scalatest.org/3.0.1-2.12/org/scalatest/Reporter.html):

> Trait whose instances collect the results of a running suite of tests
>   and presents those results in some way to the user.

Override `apply` method to handle [test events](http://doc.scalatest.org/3.0.1-2.12/org/scalatest/events/index.html):

```
class MyReporter extends Reporter {
  def apply(event: Event): Unit = {
    event match {
      case event: InfoProvided => 
      case event: TestFailed =>
      case ...
      case _ =>
    }
  }
}
```

Configure SBT to use custom reporter like so via `-C` argument:

```
Test / testOptions += Tests.Argument("-C", "example.MyReporter")
```

Here is a working example [scalatest-custom-reporter-example](https://github.com/mario-galic/scalatest-custom-reporter-example).

Comment: This is especially great for mix-and-match suites that import multiple SpecLikes

Answer (score 1):

I looked through the documentation again after Mario's answer and seems like there is in fact built-in functionality for use cases like mine

http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/using_scalatest_with_sbt

```
Using Reporters
You can use ScalaTest's reporters by specifying the passing the following arguments to ScalaTest:

-f[configs...] <filename> - causes test results to be written to the named file
-u <directory> - causes test results to be written to junit-style xml files in the named directory
-h <directory> [-Y ] - causes test results to be written to HTML files in the named directory, optionally included the specified CSS file
-a <number of files to archive> - causes specified number of old summary and durations files to be archived (in summaries/ and durations/ subdirectories) for dashboard reporter (default is two)
-o[configs...] - causes test results to be written back to sbt, which usually displays it on the standard output
-e[configs...] - causes test results to be written to the standard error
-k <host> <port> - causes test results to be written to socket in the named host and port number, using XML format
-K <host> <port> - causes test results to be written to socket in the named host and port number, using Java object binary format
-C[configs...] <reporterclass> - causes test results to be reported to an instance of the specified fully qualified Reporter class name
```