# How to pass custom information to Reporter in Scala Test?

Tags: scala, scalatest, scalatest-maven-plugin

Our scala test case calls a REST API for ex. creating a user and it checks if the userId is actually created or not by parsing the output response.
In case the REST API throws any error, the userId is empty and the customReport shows the event as TestFailed with `org.scalatest.exceptions.TestFailedException: "" equaled ""` due to the assert condition (assert(userId != ""))

Is there a way that I can pass the response of REST API to the reporter.
Please advise.

```
class CustomReport extends Reporter {


  override def apply(event: Event): Unit = {

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider providing custom information on failure via [clue](http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/using_assertions), for example,

```
assert(userId != "", myCustomInformation)
```

or

```
withClue(myCustomInformation) {
  userId should not be empty
}
```

where `customInformation` could be, say,

```
case class MyCustomInformation(name: String, id: Int)
val myCustomInformation = MyCustomInformation("picard", 42)
```

Here is a working example

```
import org.scalatest._

class ClueSpec extends FlatSpec with Matchers {
  case class MyCustomInformation(name: String, id: Int)

  "Tests failures" should "annotated with clues" in {
    withClue(MyCustomInformation("picard", 42)) {
      "" should not be empty
    }
  }
}
```

which outputs

```
[info] Tests failures
[info] - should annotated with clues *** FAILED ***
[info]   MyCustomInformation(picard,42) "" was empty (HelloSpec.scala:10)
```

For an example of custom reporter consider https://stackoverflow.com/a/56790804/5205022